# How to perform POST request on a randomly generated request url?

Tags: python, post, get, python-requests

On this website, the request url has a randomy generated string at the end of the link. There is no trace of the value that is going to be added to the end of it until the 'login' button is clicked.

How do I go about getting or generating the same url to perform a login.

I looked at the site and one function is:

```
function generateAjaxToken(url) {
    var key = randomString(16);
    var value = randomString(16);
    document.cookie = "ATERNOS_SEC_" + key + "=" + value + ";path=" + url;
    return key + ":" + value;
}
```

The website is https://aternos.org/go/

Comment: this doesn't look like python at all, how does this relate to python exactly?

Comment: What does a sample URL look like? Can you extract the URL value from the cookie that is set on the client?

Comment: @aws_apprentice that's the code on the site, not my python code. I posted it to show that the site generates the request url randomly.

Comment: @SamChats I checked the cookies when I am on the site but there is no instance of that cookie. This cookie is generated on the click of the login button, and the cookie value is used for the request url.

Comment: @SamChats Request URL: https://aternos.org/panel/ajax/account/login.php?ASEC=px1k2gcbhu000000%3A0wgk5ut6hewm0000

Comment: if page uses JavaScrip then you may need Selenium to control web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: you could  try to generate random string which looks similar to string generated by JavaScript and add it to cookies and to url.